# MySQL select x number of records from table by column

Tags: mysql

Probably the worst title ever. What I have is a table of 3 columns

```
id | name | type
1  | John | 1
2  | Sam  | 1
3  | Bob  | 2
4  | Joe  | 2
5  | Al   | 3
6  | Paul | 3
```

I need to select 3 random people that have different types

A valid output would be

```
id | name | type
1  | John | 1
3  | Bob  | 2
6  | Paul | 3
```

An invalid output would be

```
id | name | type
3  | Bob  | 2
5  | Al   | 3
6  | Paul | 3
```

What I thought I could do is

```
SELECT id, name, type FROM table WHERE type = 1
UNION
SELECT id, name, type FROM table WHERE type = 2
UNION
SELECT id, name, type FROM table WHERE type = 3
```

But this is not really possible because this is just a simplified example, in the real code I have many more columns to select and perform joins and if I did it this way it would be horribly unmaintainable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that uses variables.  Presumably, you want a random record of each type:

```
select id, name, type
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = type, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := type, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from table t cross join
           (select @t := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      order by type, rand()
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I could really benefit if you could explain the idea behind it, because it appears too complex for me.

Comment: yeah use this and nobody will ever understand your sql or can fix bugs. :O

Answer (score 1):

why not try something with group by.

```
 select id,name,type from table group by type order by rand() limit 0,XXX
```

Comment: I couldn't use group by because then it would merge all my records from the joins I perform

Comment: Actually, the above code looks to be the way to go. If you need to join something else with this one, integrate this query as a subtable into the main query.

Comment: Oh and you don't need the limit clause